# Xamarin.forms - Displaying content with WebView

Tags: c#, webview, xamarin.forms, html-agility-pack

I'm creating a mobile app of existing website. I use HTMLAGILITYPACK to scrap some data from website. I want to display them in my app. But there is no result and nothing displays.

This is my App code with "scraper":

```
namespace Apka
{
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static string DocumentPath = 
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    public static string strona = "";


    public static NavigationPage NavigationPage { get; private set; }
    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("www.wiocha.pl");
    WebResponse response;

    public App()
    {


        InitializeComponent();

        starthttp();





        NavigationPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        RootPage rootPage = new RootPage();
        MenuPage menuPage = new MenuPage(rootPage.vm);

        rootPage.Master = menuPage;
        rootPage.Detail = NavigationPage;
        MainPage = rootPage;

    }


    private async void starthttp()
    {

        response = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);

        var html = new HtmlDocument();
        html.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
        var nodes = html.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
            .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
               .Equals("imageitself")).ToList();





        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {

            strona = strona + node.OuterHtml;

        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(strona);




    }
}
```

}
In console it returns some img in html like img src="link" class="imageitself" alt="blablabla"

Here is my page where im trying to place scraped pictures:

```
namespace Apka.View.Pages
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {



        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            WebView webView = new WebView
            {
                Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
                {
                    Html = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>img { width:100%; }</style></head><body>" + App.strona + @"</body></html>",
                },
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand

            };



            /* ViewModel.Pages.MainPageViewModel vm = new ViewModel.Pages.MainPageViewModel();
             this.BindingContext = vm;*/
        }





    }
}
```

And XAML code to this page looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="" (cant place links)
         xmlns:x="" (here too)
         x:Class="Apka.View.Pages.MainPage">


<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Command="{Binding MenuItem1Command}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#505050" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">



    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Why webview doesn't work? What should I do to display these pictures?

Comment: Elaborate *doesn't work*? Any logs, any symptoms?

Comment: No errors, app starst and works but webview doesn't exist. It looks like there is no webview statement in the scope. I only see background color which I set in XAML

Comment: @BartekCebo Please see my answer and you'll understand why it *"doesn't exist"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your `WebView` with the following code

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WebView webView = new WebView
        {
            // elided
        };


        /* ViewModel.Pages.MainPageViewModel vm = new ViewModel.Pages.MainPageViewModel();
         this.BindingContext = vm;*/
    }
```

Anyway, there is no place where you are **adding** the `WebView` to your page. If you really want to create the `WebView` from code, you'll have to give a name to the `StackLayout`

```
<StackLayout x:Name="StackLayout" ...>
```

and then add the `WebView` from your `MainPage` constructor.

```
StackLayout.Children.Add(webView);
```

Anyway, there is nothing that prevents you from creating he `WebView` from XAML

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="#505050" 
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <WebView x:Name="WebView" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand />
</StackLayout>
```

and then simply set the source in code behind

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    WebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
                     {
                         Html = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>img { width:100%; }</style></head><body>" + App.strona + @"</body></html>",
                     };
}
```

Comment: Hm, this ought work. Are you sure that the name given in `x:Name="..."` is the very same you are using to access the `StackLayout` from code behind?

Comment: The error means that there is no field or property `StackLayout` in your `MainPage`, but when you add the `x:Name` attribute one is generated for you in `MainPage.xaml.g.cs` (this is a compiler generated file you don't have to worry about). Please note that the name given is *case sensitive*!

Comment: OK, I tried to do it creating WebView from XAML as you suggested and then setting code behind as well as you suggested. Now the VisualStudio gives me an error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, methods or properties of the "WebView.Source" "

Comment: UFF you are right. When I compiled it, it started. But the only thing I see is white blank page. I dont know why

Comment: Do you have any ideas why I see nothing apart of white?

Comment: Just try to set the source to "www.google.de" in XAML (and remove the assignment from code behind) to verify that the `WebView` is showing correctly. If so, I assume that the `App.strona` field is unset or something.

Comment: Hmm, google works and shows correctly. Result of System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine(strona) is : [0:] <img src="http://img.wiocha.pl/images/9/2/92aea60671237feaf69a1d3c5a4f2563.jpg?s=1532511562" class="imageitself" alt="Celny" title="Celny">

Comment: I have no idea why there is a problem with displaying it

Comment: I discovered that Visual studio doesn't understand that text between " " in html = " " is html code. When you put there img with src it thinks that // after http:// mean comment. Also, It doesn't understand additional "" inside html code and treats it as end of html declaration.

Comment: But i have no idea how to avoid missunderstanding html code by VisualStudio

Comment: Are you sure that *"Visual studio doesn't understand that text between ..."*? In the HTML you provided there is an additional `;`, isn't it?

Comment: When I changed " to ' in html part, it worked poperly. Thanks for help! :)

Comment: Sweet...was looking of xaml solution...Ill get the horizontal and vertical down one day.

Answer (score 1):

On the page where declaring the WebView, when is added into a stacklayout needs specified the WidthRequest and HeightRequest of the WebView for displayed, not occurs when is added into a GridLayout, for this case

```
namespace Apka.View.Pages
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{



    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        WebView webView = new WebView
        {
            Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
            {
                Html = @"<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>img { width:100%; }</style></head><body>" + App.strona + @"</body></html>",
            },
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            WidthRequest = 1000,
            HeightRequest=1000

        };



        /* ViewModel.Pages.MainPageViewModel vm = new ViewModel.Pages.MainPageViewModel();
         this.BindingContext = vm;*/
    }
}
}
```